# Firebase firestore check if document has collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to check if a document has a collection rather than checking if it has fields
 Thanks

Comment: Your question is kind of vague, since everything in firebase is essentially a field. Can you clarify what you mean by a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no client SDK APIs for listing subcollections of a document.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer