# Is it possible to check if a document has a subcollection in firestore?

Tags: firebase, recursion, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write a recursive function in which I can pass in a document reference and delete that document and it's subcollections. I was thinking that the base case would be that the document has no subcollections. If it has a subcollection, I would pass that subcollection into the recursive function, and delete any existing documents. If not, I would simply delete that document and return. So is there someway I can check if a document has a subcollection, and if so retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

According to Doug Stevenson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535095/firebase-firestore-check-if-document-has-collection) there are no client SDK APIs for listing subcollections of a document.

Although you may find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286764/delete-a-document-with-all-subcollections-and-nested-subcollections-in-firestore?rq=1) but that also may create further problems. In [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) also deleting collections from an Android client is not recommended.

Comment: Did you find the answer or any other workaround? If not, please accept the answer and upvote it so that others will get benefit too.